# Sum of fractional parts in $(1,2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c$ be any rational, non-integer positive numbers with non-integer sum. Does there always exist a positive integer $k$ such that $ka,kb,kc$ are not integers and $\{ka\}+\{kb\}+\{kc\}\in(1,2)$?

($\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$, that is $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.)

Kronecker's density theorem works in a similar setting, saying that the set $\{\{kx\}\}$ is dense, but it holds only for irrational numbers $x$, which is not the case here.

When $a=b=c$, we want $3\{ka\}\in(1,2)$, or $\{ka\}\in(1/3,2/3)$. The condition prohibits $a=n+1/3$ or $a=n+2/3$ for some integer $n$. If $\{a\}\in(1/3,2/3)$ we are done immediately. If $\{a\}<1/3$ then by repeatedly multiplying by two, we eventually have $\{ka\}\in(1/3,2/3)$. Similarly if $\{a\}>2/3$.